# Separating empty folders from folders which only contain other folders

Tags: python

I have a set of files and a set of folders.

This part seems to work:

```
file_folders = {p.parent for p in files}
no_file_folders = folders - file_folders
```

But this part seems to not be correct:

```
no_file_folders_parents = {p.parent for p in no_file_folders}
folder_folders = no_file_folders & no_file_folders_parents
empty_folders = no_file_folders - folder_folders
```

How can I correctly separate empty folders (containing no other folders) and folders which only contain folders?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking to do the same thing this seems to work:

```py
file_folders = {p.parent for p in files}
no_file_folders = folders - file_folders

parents = {p.parent.parent for p in files} | {p.parent for p in no_file_folders}
folder_folders = no_file_folders & parents
empty_folders = no_file_folders - folder_folders

assert all(list(p.glob('*')) != [] for p in folder_folders)
assert all(list(p.glob('*')) == [] for p in empty_folders)
```